# UNIFIL "Blue Line" barrel marking coordinates

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a dataset of UNIFIL's Israel-Lebanon "Blue Line" coordinates, preferably with the barrel marker name.

I've already looked in UNIFIL and UN's peacekeeping sites, as well as UN data portal, but no luck.

I've collated a few tidbits of coordinates from technical specifications here and there, but since there are ~500 markers, that's not good.

For those wondering, I'm trying to see the effect of the border demarcation on ecologic succession and vegetation dynamics in the region.

Comment: While it does not contain the barrels, the OSM [state boundary of Libanon](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/184843) does follow the lower Blue line, whereas the relation for [Litani River](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/384062) follows the northern UNIFIL zone border as described on the [Blue Line Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Line_%28Lebanon%29) article.

Comment: That's not the Blue Line. I;m familiar with the OSM interpretation of it and it's incorrect. Neither is Google's (Actually US Department of State Geographer). That is why I'm asking for the coordinates from the body entrusted to demarcate the line, the UN.